Handing something to a woman (opposite gender)
Is it prohibited to hand something to a woman (or the opposite gender)?
Example: giving change or a receipt to a female customer.
My logic for giving this example is that the Lubavitcher Rebbe was known for handing out dollar bills (for tzedaka) to men and woman.

If your motivating example is of a Rabbi handing things to women what is your reason for asking whether it's prohibited?

What do you think might be the issue? They are not touching each other?

It is permitted to hand an item to someone of the opposite gender*, even if the hands touch, although it is recommended to try to do so in a way that avoids touch, so long as it won't make a scene or lead to embarrassment of the other.
See this dinonline teshuva regarding handing change to a customer.
* unless they are husband and wife and it is during Niddah

The Igrot Moshe on derech chiba is relevant here, handing something to someone is not done in an affectionate way, or to touch the other person but ... to hand something over

@mbloch I wanted to avoid getting into the reasoning because this could devolve into a "what's wrong with handshakes" conversation :) Suffice it to say that this case is permitted

Is this https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1082&st=&pgnum=490&hilite= (#7) the source for the psak?

@TheTargum it's the source for the dinonline teshuva, but I wouldn't exactly call it the source for permission to hand things to the opposite gender

@RabbiKaii Okay, thank you
